# Transpose SQL result that pulls column names and datatype

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer. I want to run a SQL query that pulls column_name, data_type and nullable values from a certain table. I can accomplish this by running the following code:

```
select column_name, data_type, nullable
from all_tab_columns
where table_name = 'mytable'
order by column_id asc
```

This outputs results as such:

```
Column_Name | Data_Type | Nullable
-----------------------------------
Column 1    | VARCHAR2  | N
Column 2    | NUMBER    | Y
Column 3    | DATE      | N
```

In order to make this information useful to me, I need to transpose this data so that column_name is all one row (right now its all one column) and its corresponding data below it. It should look something like this.

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3
------------------------------
VARCHAR2 | NUMBER   | DATE
N        | Y        | N
```

Does anyone know the best way to go about doing this? In Teradata, this was as easy as running a case command, but it doesn't seem to be the case (pun) here in Oracle. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added edits.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `listagg()` to put everything into one string column:

```
select listagg(column_name || ',' || data_type || ',' || nullable, ';') within group (order by column_id asc)
from all_tab_columns
where table_name = 'mytable'
```

Comment: The issue with this is that it just make it one large string, which isn't particularly useful to me. I appreciate the effort though!